# Reference-counting caveats in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, garbage-collection, raii, reference-counting

I've long considered myself a garbage collection snob – despite a secret love for C++, I find myself sneering at developers who actively choose to use languages without (read: *missing*) garbage collection when they're given the option.

And then I met Objective-C. Wow! Its system of reference counting seems brilliantly simple – I'd even go so far as to say *elegant*. When developing for OSX, developers are given the option to use a snazzy GC; when developing for iOS, developers are stuck with reference counting.

### My question is:

If I am developing an OSX application that could *potentially* be ported to iOS, is Objective-C's reference counting system time-consuming enough (development-wise and bug-fixing-wise) to warrant ignoring it for the application's first version?

What problems am I **likely** to run into if I rely on reference counting*, assuming I'm not clever enough to construct any diabolically complex cyclical data structures? With features like `autorelease`, **it all seems so easy,** but I know that Apple wouldn't have invested the effort into creating a garbage collector if this were really the case. What should I be on the lookout for?

* I am aware that I can use the garbage collector even if I am throwing around `retain`s and `release`s (they'll be ignored). However, considering non-GC applications often use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), I don't understand how that would work if a generational GC were to "replace" calls to `retain` and `release`. Wouldn't resources potentially be released late?

Comment: Is kind of time consuming but you should not ignore them try your best and probably in the 2nd 3rd app you will really get it ;) Is time invested in you. MUST READ: http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/

Comment: +1 Thank you for the link! I'll read that tomorrow morning.

Comment: Once you're accustomed to it it's clean and simple, and requires little extra effort. Like you said, it really is pretty elegant. You rarely need to even deal with autorelease pools (which are less memory efficient than releasing stuff the moment it's no longer needed) because most things can be manually retained and released with ease.

Comment: That was a nifty link! I'm going to go ahead and and implement reference counting in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with developing code to port to iOS is that taking GC only code and back porting it to reference counting is a bit tedious and time consuming and potentially error prone.  Having said that, as long as you use properties (make them retain even though it makes no difference in GC) as much as possible and you enable the static analyser build phase, it's not too bad.  The static analyser will catch most failures to observe the memory management rules.  It won't notice if you fail to release an ivar in dealloc, but you can go through and systematically add all the dealloc methods.

Bear in mind that you can't directly port a Mac application to the iPhone, the VC part of MVC has to be completely rewritten, so you could take the approach of writing the Mac UI solely for garbage collection and only make the model classes compatible with both GC and reference counting.